# Spring Boot: insert date in database in dd/mm/yyyy format

Tags: java, database, spring-boot, date, date-formatting

I was trying to follow a question on this site with my same problem, which is to insert the date into the database in the format dd/mm/yyyy, only it doesn't work.

So I also ask the question hoping to solve this problem; I explain better:

I have the date written in the following way

```java
@JsonFormat(pattern="dd/MM/yyyy")
private Date datebirth;
```

I try to test it with Postman by entering the date as:
"datebirth": "31/05/2021"}

and when I go to save it in the db "datebirth" it is saved as:
2021-05-31 01:00:00 (*but I want the date to be in the format dd/mm/yyyy and I don't want it to be 01:00:00*)

How can I solve this problem, then get the date exclusively in the 31/05/2021 format?

Save-student method in Controller:

```java
@PostMapping("save-student")
public boolean saveStudent(@RequestBody Student student) throws IOException{
    return studentservice.saveStudent(student);
}
```

Comment: I recommend that in Java you don’t use `Date`. That class is poorly designed and long outdated. Instead use `LocalDate` from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Comment: No, you are wrong. You don’t want to save the date in dd/mm/yyyy format in the database. Had you wanted that, you would have needed to save it as a char type. You want to use the database’ `date` datatype and leave it to the engine in what format it stores it. An no, it is not stored as `2021-05-31 01:00:00`. It is *printed* like that when you retrieve it. It is stored in an internal format, probably a binary one, and we should not care. When you retrieve the date, you want to format it in a way that is readable for your user and yourself.

Comment: `2021-05-31 01:00:00` seems to indicate that you are using some `datetime`data type of your database. Why? If you want to store the date without time of day, prefer the `Date` data type that almost all database engines offer. And the value will already be more readable. Which database engine are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way Java saves dates by default is using the ISO-8601 format which is in the form yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss. You can use one of the standard Java date time formatting libraries such as Joda-Time or LocalDate or DateTimeFormatter or SimpleDate to format your date to the 'dd/MM/yyyy' format once you've retrieved it from the database.

Here's an example using SimpleDate to format to dd/MM/yyyy:

```
String pattern = "dd/MM/yyyy";
SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(pattern);

String date = simpleDateFormat.format(new Date());
System.out.println(date);
```