# Springboot add yyyy-MM-dd to database using hibernate

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa

I have a Date object like 2022-11-09 in my Reservation class, but whenever it gets added to the database and I run the query select * from reservations. I get an output like:
2022-11-09 01:00:00

Now this causes a lot of problems since I would like to return all objects that have date 2022-11-09 . Every time no objects are returned since JPARepo doesn't return anything probably because my Date object doesn't match the SQL's Date (with time).

To give you more information I will add some screenshots and code:

```
@Entity(name = "reservations")
public class Reservation {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    private Date date;

    private Boolean voormiddag;
    private Boolean namiddag;

    private Long roomId;
    private String username;
```

select * from reservations returns:
[image]

Is there a way to just store the java Date-Object (yyyy-MM-dd) as the same format (so without time) in the database?

I found these solutions, but they change my Date object to type String and this is NOT what I want:
[image: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67794434/spring-boot-insert-date-in-database-in-dd-mm-yyyy-format8]

Comment: Yes and no. The date in your database hasn’t got a format, only an internal binary format that we don’t want to know about. So it depends on your RDBMS (database engine/brand) how it prints the date when you retrieve it, but I would suppose that if you use data type `date` instead of `timestamp without time zone`, then it will print exactly `2022-11-09`.

Comment: In Java I strongly recommend that you don’t use any of the two `Date` classes nor `SimpleDateFormat` since they are all troublesome and outdated. Use `LocalDate` from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html). And a `DateTimeFormatter` in case you need to format or parse dates. Hibernate supports java.time at least since version 5.